# 'unstable value' in reference to time % 12345

Tags: go, kubernetes

In [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/79cb21f5b3b1dd8f8b23bd3f79925b4fda4e2562/tools/cache/reflector.go#L100) reflector package it mentions an unstable value being used as a name suffix. It's the number of nanoseconds modulo 12345. Is this meaningful or is it just a synonym for pseudo random so humans don't interpret it?

```
// reflectorDisambiguator is used to disambiguate started reflectors.
// initialized to an unstable value to ensure meaning isn't attributed to the suffix.
var reflectorDisambiguator = int64(time.Now().UnixNano() % 12345)
```

The word unstable is what is specifically making me unsure. What does it mean in this context?

Is there an advantage of doing this over another method of getting a random number under 12345?

Comment: See what it was changed from https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/commit/755bbca820db30c1a1d071d0ab4709fc49c003a5 Interesting...

Comment: @zerkms The commit message makes it sound like it was done just to avoid the collision of selecting the same truncated number twice. They solved that with the atomic adding 1 per operation though. And rand is used elsewhere in the file, so it's not removing an import to not use it here. This just made me more confused haha.

Comment: it looks like that method is invoked rather frequently, what made the original implementation prone to the [Birthday Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). So if true randomness is not required - the solution is legit

Comment: @zerkms I agree, that's what the commit message says it was solving. The question still remains. Why didn't they just set the variable outside the fnc with the rand.Intn instead of changing over to the nanosecond manipulation?

Comment: @Brian:  `rand.Intn` is expensive overkill.

Comment: @peterSO isn't it done once per application run though

Comment: @zerkms: It's good practice to use an appropriate algorithm. A simple solution for a simple problem. Minimal startup times are important.

Comment: Also as discussed below rand.Intn was deterministic, which besides the birthday attack may cause collisions on application restarts. I believe that was the real motive. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning seems clear:

> [Kubernetes-commit: 1da4f4a745bf536c34e377321a252b4774d1a7e0](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/commit/755bbca820db30c1a1d071d0ab4709fc49c003a5)
>
> tools/cache/reflector.go
>
> ```
> // reflectorDisambiguator is used to disambiguate started reflectors.
> // initialized to an unstable value to ensure meaning isn't attributed to the suffix.
> ```

The suffix behavior should not be deterministic because you should not rely on a particular implementation behavior.

---

For example, a similar situation occured for Go maps:

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> For statements with range clause
>
> The iteration order over maps is not specified and is not guaranteed
>   to be the same from one iteration to the next.
>
> [Go 1 Release Notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1)
>
> Iterating in maps
>
> The old language specification did not define the order of iteration
>   for maps, and in practice it differed across hardware platforms. This
>   caused tests that iterated over maps to be fragile and non-portable,
>   with the unpleasant property that a test might always pass on one
>   machine but break on another.
>
> In Go 1, the order in which elements are visited when iterating over a
>   map using a for range statement is defined to be unpredictable, even
>   if the same loop is run multiple times with the same map. Code should
>   not assume that the elements are visited in any particular order.
>
> This change means that code that depends on iteration order is very
>   likely to break early and be fixed long before it becomes a problem.
>   Just as important, it allows the map implementation to ensure better
>   map balancing even when programs are using range loops to select an
>   element from a map.
>
> [Go 1.3 Release Notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.3)
>
> Map iteration
>
> Iterations over small maps no longer happen in a consistent order. Go
>   1 defines that “The iteration order over maps is not specified and is
>   not guaranteed to be the same from one iteration to the next.” To keep
>   code from depending on map iteration order, Go 1.0 started each map
>   iteration at a random index in the map. A new map implementation
>   introduced in Go 1.1 neglected to randomize iteration for maps with
>   eight or fewer entries, although the iteration order can still vary
>   from system to system. This has allowed people to write Go 1.1 and Go
>   1.2 programs that depend on small map iteration order and therefore only work reliably on certain systems. Go 1.3 reintroduces random
>   iteration for small maps in order to flush out these bugs.
>
> Updating: If code assumes a fixed iteration order for small maps, it
>   will break and must be rewritten not to make that assumption. Because
>   only small maps are affected, the problem arises most often in tests.

---

Similar concerns lead to a proposal, that wasn't implemented, to ensure that the order for unstable sorts was unstable:

> [proposal: sort: return equal values in non-deterministic order#13884](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13884)
>
> Crazy idea, but what if sort.Sort randomly permuted its input a bit
>   before starting?
>
> Go 1.6 has a different sort.Sort than Go 1.5 and I've seen at least a
>   dozen test failures at Google that were implicitly depending on the
>   old algorithm. The usual scenario is that you sort a slice of structs
>   by one field in the struct. If there are entries with that field equal
>   but others unequal and you expect a specific order for the structs at
>   the end, you are depending on sort.Sort's algorithm. A later sort.Sort
>   might make a different choice and produce a different order. This
>   makes programs not portable from one version of Go to another, much
>   like map hash differences used to make programs not portable from one
>   architecture to another. We solved maps by randomizing the iteration
>   order a bit. In the map case it's not a full permutation, but just
>   enough variation to make tests obviously flaky.
>
> I wonder if we should do the same for sort.Sort. It would only take N
>   swaps to shuffle things quite well, and we already use Nlog(N) swaps,
>   so N(log(N)+1) is not likely to be noticed. That would also protect a
>   bit against malicious inputs.
>
> It would surprise people, especially people who think sort.Sort ==
>   sort.Stable. But the rationale is that it's better to surprise them
>   the first time they run the code instead of however many Go releases
>   later.

---

Here are benchmarks comparing `time.Now()` to `rand.Intn()`:

```
package main

import "testing"

import (
    rand "math/rand"
    "time"
)

// https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/79cb21f5b3b1dd8f8b23bd3f79925b4fda4e2562/tools/cache/reflector.go#L100
var reflectorDisambiguator = int64(time.Now().UnixNano() % 12345)

func BenchmarkTimeNow(b *testing.B) {
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        reflectorDisambiguator = int64(time.Now().UnixNano() % 12345)
    }
}

// rand.Intn()
func init() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    reflectorDisambiguator = int64(rand.Intn(12345))
}

func BenchmarkRandIntn(b *testing.B) {
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
        reflectorDisambiguator = int64(rand.Intn(12345))
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go test disambiguator_test.go -bench=.
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkTimeNow-4      20000000            67.5 ns/op
BenchmarkRandIntn-4       100000         11941 ns/op
$
```

Comment: I didn't realize that math/rand used a deterministic source. `var ModuloRand = int64(time.Now().UnixNano() % 12345)` is different every run but `var IntnRand = rand.Intn(12345)` is the same every time I ran. Thanks!

Comment: @Brian: For a pseudorandom value of `var IntnRand` write `var IntnRand int; func init() { rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano()); IntnRand = rand.Intn(12345) }`. See my revised answer for benchmarks.

Comment: @peterSO oh wow, they save impressive 12 microseconds every app start! (sorry for being sarcastic) :-D

Comment: @zerkms: Kubernetes, like Go, was designed at Google to operate at Google scale. Kubernetes: Planet Scale: Designed on the same principles that allows Google to run billions of containers a week. https://kubernetes.io/ So multiply numbers by billions, trillions, .... In your small world it might not matter.

Comment: @peterSO I agree. The problem is that you still assume they micro-optimised that place, not followed some other aims (which is likely, since the current implementation is too dirty)